# jquery disable dragging

Tags: jquery

I have draggable Jquery UI box and Jquery UI tabs inside. Buts it is dragable too. How to diable it?

Comment: You need to show us the code you are using to properly answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jqueryObject.draggable('disable');
```

Answer (score 2):

try to take a look to this example, to see if it helps:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle