# jQuery-UI Disable dragging for some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am making a desktop-like website, and I want to drag my windows around. I am using `jQuery-UI` and `.draggable()`. My current code looks like this:

```
<div id="window"> <!-- You'll drag this whole div -->
    <div id="title">Window name</div> <!-- You drag with this -->
    <div id="content"></div> <!-- You cannot drag this -->
</div>
```

And with my JS I just did this:

```
$("#window").draggable();
```

I want this because I need to select text from #content, which is hard to do if it's `draggable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I think should be...

```
$("#content").draggable('disable');
```

There was a similar question to this here... [jquery disable dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804892/jquery-disable-dragging)

Comment: Thanks, works! I saw in the article you posted the link to http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle which was very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this

```
$("#window").draggable({ handle: "title" });
```